# Triangle has angles $x$, $3x$, and $x+15^\circ$. How do I solve for $x$?

Tags: geometry, triangles

I came across this problem and I understand that I am supposed to find the $x$ first. In order to do that, I believe that an equation is required. How do I solve this?

[image]

Comment: Yes, you need an equation.  What do we know about the three angle of a triangle?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $x+3x+x+15^{\circ}=180^{\circ}$ for each Euclidian triangle